# What do I call in PHP to check if a string matches a pattern?

Tags: php, bit.ly

I found [this URL shortener code][1] on the web.

Now I want to add something.  I want to throw an error to user if they enter a link from bit.ly, TinyURL.com or tr.im.  I want it to say, "Sorry, we do not shorten short URLs." I know I need to create an `if` and `else` statement, but I don't know what things I need to call.

#### Edit:

Thanks a lot for the input!  Unfortunately I am totally confused.  Where do I place these code suggestions?  At the top of the index.php.  Right now I have the following php code..

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');

if ($url = get_url())
{
    $conn = open_connection();
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `urls` WHERE `url`='$url' LIMIT 1", $conn);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res))
    {
        // this URL entry already exists in the database
        // get its ID instead
        $row = mysql_fetch_object($res);
        $id = $row->id;
    }
    else
    {
        // a new guy, insert it now and get its ID
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `urls`(`url`) VALUES('$url')", $conn);
        $id = mysql_insert_id($conn);
    }

    // now convert the ID into its base36 instance
    $code = base_convert($id, 10, 36);
    $shorten_url = "{$config['host']}/$code";

    // and beautifully display the shortened URL
    $info = sprintf('
<span class="long-url" style="visibility: hidden;">%s</span>
<span style="visibility: hidden">%d</span> <br>
    Link to drop:
    <a class="shorteen-url" href="%s">%s</a>
    <span style="visibility: hidden">%d</span>',
        $_GET['url'], strlen($_GET['url']),
        $shorten_url, $shorten_url,
        strlen($shorten_url));
}

?>
```

I'm not using `$info = sprintf` ... maybe I should replace `$info = sprintf` with one of the suggestions below?

Comment: here is the URL shortening code http://www.phoenixheart.net/2009/06/write-your-own-url-shortener/comment-page-1/#comment-4916

Comment: FWIW, bit.ly answers requests directed to its IPs directly.  e.g.: http://128.121.254.129/nmP3X is the same as http://bit.ly/nmP3X

Additionally, there are hundreds of shorteners out there -- awe.sm, digg.com, etc. etc.; attempting to enumerate them all is fairly futile.

Comment: Yeah. We might suggest a check more along the lines of `if(strlen($url) < 20)`.

Comment: @chaos: that check would leave out correct urls, too. What about a.blogspot.com?

Comment: chaos's suggestion works if you replace `20` with the length of your shortener's urls. if the link doesn't qualify (ie. `a.blogspot.com`) then give a message stating "sorry but we can't make that link any shorter". if your shortener can produce a shorter url than another shortener, one might argue that you are still providing a service.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(preg_match('!^(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:bit\.ly|tinyurl\.com|tr\.im)/!i', $url))
    die("Sorry, we do not shorten short URLs.");
```

Comment: I think you need one of these ^ to make that complete ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to check if the URL already was shortened:

```
if(preg_match('#^https?://[^/]*?(tinyurl\.com|tr\.im|bit\.ly)#i', $myUrl) {
    echo "Sorry, we do not shorten short URLs.";
} else {
    echo "We can shorten that!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For these cases, in which you know exactly the urls to match, and they aren't patterns, `strpos` is simpler than the `preg` functions.

[`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) takes the string to check, the match, an optional offset, and returns FALSE if the match wasn't in the string.

```
$url_chk = strtolower($original_url);
if (strpos($url_chk, 'bit.ly') === FALSE
 || strpos($url_chk, 'tinyurl.com')  === FALSE
 || strpos($url_chk, 'tr.im') === FALSE) {
    echo "Sorry, we do not shorten short URLs.";
} else {
    echo "We can shorten that!";
}
```

**EDIT**: I change the original url to lowercase to simplify the match, since the user might have submitted the url as tinyURL.com, for example.

**SECOND EDIT** To answer your followup: it seems the string with the shortened url is created in the line

```
$shorten_url = "{$config['host']}/$code";
```

which means that `$config['host']` should contain the relevant portion of the URL. But it's not clear where that comes from. At a guess, it's created in config.php.

Our suggestions using `die()` or `echo()` are just suggestions, don't embed this directly into your sprintf or your code without actually adapting them.

Comment: Two issues: if strpos() returns 0, your code will fail to match.  Also, it will falsely match http://example.com/some/path/tr.im/woo

Comment: Corrected the first issue, but not the second. It's a drawback of the solution, yes, but I think it's arguable whether it's worth it to use the preg_s or not. A more realistic example could be 'www.getattr.im', for that matter. Other people argued that the number of url shorteners is so big enumerating them is useless. Doing more than -say- 5 leaves you with an unsightly regex, too.